# Can't enter my website because server DNS address could not be found

Tags: asp.net, iis, dns

I'm trying to publish a test website online using Visual Studio 2015 (asp.net) and iis version 10.

I created a new website with iis, directed it to the website directory which I made sure has got all the permissions for iis.

I also created an empty website on Visual Studio and published it using file system to the directory described above.

I gave my website a host name of testSite.com (while creating a website in iis), when I try to connect to my website I get:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> testSite.com’s server DNS address could not be found

I tried to set an IP address and DNS configuration to my internet Wi-Fi connection but it stopped all my network connection.

Also, when I leave the host name empty (in iis website creation), I can successfully connect to the website by browsing localhost so the problem occurs only when I change the host name.

What should I do to solve that problem and get connected to my website?

Thank you, Dan.

Comment: Just from doing a quick Google search I found this: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/0qkak_17qb0
hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for replying, that unfortunately didn't help me, I still get the same error.